# How to open a file in powershell, by entering the variable which contains the file's path?

Tags: powershell, execution

In `powershell`, like in `cmd`, you have to type the path to the file, including the file itself , or if you are in the same location as the one where the file is located, you have to type just the files name, below is shown an example for each case :

```
# if the file is a different location
[Path to the file]\[fileName]

# if the file is in the same location
.\[fileName]
```

What I want to do is to assign the path to the file to a variable, and just type the variable name, when I want to open the file, like this :

```
$path = [fileLocation + fileName]
```

But, the problem is, that when I type the variable, PowerShell, returns me the string value of the `$path` , and so, how can I launch a file by having it's path assigned to a variable?

Comment: What do you mean by launch. Like take you to the path or run a command from that path. Like a example of how you would like to use it please

Comment: As an aside: Invoking an executable located in the current dir. by name only (`foo`) does _not_ work in PowerShell, for security reasons. To do so you must use at least use a relative path (`.\foo`).

Comment: Let's assume, that you have an `.exe` file, you launch it by double-clicking the file, and for doing the same, in cmd/powershell, you have to type the path to the file in console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the `&` sign before typing the variable which contains the path to the file like this: `& $path`